# programatically get public key token using .snk file c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a .snk file programatically and using that file I want to get the public key token?

Comment: I think your going to need to give us some more details, what youve tried, etc

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to do what you want:

```
 CspParameters parms = new CspParameters();
 parms.KeyNumber = 2;

 RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parms);
 byte[] array = provider.ExportCspBlob(!provider.PublicOnly);
 StrongNameKeyPair snk = new StrongNameKeyPair(array);
 byte[] publicKey = snk.PublicKey;
```